# How do I escape a dollar sign ('$') in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having a hard time checking if cells contain a dollar sign ('$'), as Ecxel thinks I'm trying to make an absolute reference.

I'm working with imported data that includes a column of usernames, and many of the usernames have a '$' character at the end. In Excel, I'm omitting some of the data in the username column, based on strings they may contain. Some example-ish accounts:

- chi_smithcleve
- letter_admin
- NYCDB140$
- outside3
- NYCPRD148$
- ATLDB12$
- chi_goadjames

I want to test the usernames for three conditions: they don't contain the string 'NYC', 'chi', or '$'. The character-strings are easy, but I can't figure out how to escape the dollar-sign character! All the documentation I've found suggests double-quotes as an escape mechanism in Excel, but that doesn't seem to be working. The primary formula that documentation says *should* work is:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",A2))
```

where I'm checking the cell A2 to see if the '$' character occurs. But Excel's just telling me that I have an error. I've tried several other possible escape characters, to no avail.

(I **could** do a 'character replace' function at some point upstream, to replace the '$'s with a more manipulatable character, but I'd rather just leave the data in same state as when it's received)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking about since `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",A2))` works for me. It returns TRUE if text content in `A2` contains "$" and FALSE if not.

Comment: try use  "  marks instead of  '  marks.

Comment: Please provide an exact copy of the formula and data that is returning an undesired result, and the result it is returning, when you do NOT *escape* the `$`.  I see nothing in HELP indicating that `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",A2))` should do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it is working for me.

```
  =ISNUMBER((SEARCH("$",A2)))
```

Comment: This works! I'm guessing my OS was "smart" (air quotes) replacing the "" characters with their position-sensitive counterparts: “”.

Frustrating that I can't replicate the error, but thanks for the help!